Unit tests using vue/test-utils not working with component that uses async setup
Im trying to use tests on component that is rendered asynchronously. I have tried to create simple component with async title but the problem still persists. I have added suspense around the component, added await flushPromises(); and also await wrapper.vm.$nextTick(); but nothing helps. Any recommendations?
simpleList.vue component:


<template>
  <div>
    <h1 v-if="title">{{ title }}</h1>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Slot to render custom content -->
    <slot name="customSlot"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
  name: "SimpleList",
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  async setup() {
    const title = ref('');

    // Simulate async operation to fetch the title
    const fetchTitle = async () => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          title.value = 'Async Loaded Title';
          resolve();
        }, 500); // Simulate async delay
      });
    };

    await fetchTitle();

    return {
      title,
    };
  },
};
</script>



test file:


import { mount, flushPromises } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest';
import SimpleList from '@/components/SimpleList.vue';
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

describe('SimpleList with async setup', () => {
  it('renders the title and items when wrapped in Suspense', async () => {
    const WrapperComponent = defineComponent({
      components: { SimpleList },
      template: `
        <Suspense>
          <template #default>
            <SimpleList :items="['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']" />
          </template>
          <template #fallback>
            <div>Loading...</div>
          </template>
        </Suspense>
      `
    });

    const wrapper = mount(WrapperComponent);

    // Wait for async operations
    await flushPromises();
    await flushPromises();

    // Ensure Suspense resolves
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

    // Test for the title rendered from async setup
    const title = wrapper.find('h1');
    expect(title.exists()).toBe(true);
    expect(title.text()).toBe('Async Title');

    // Test for the list items
    const listItems = wrapper.findAll('li');
    expect(listItems).toHaveLength(3);
    expect(listItems[0].text()).toBe('Item 1');
    expect(listItems[1].text()).toBe('Item 2');
    expect(listItems[2].text()).toBe('Item 3');
  });
});




Consider posting real code instead of made-up fetchTitle  as the way it needs to be tested depends on it. It's preferable to have it defined in another module, so it could be easily mocked

Managed to fix it with adding useFakeTimers and then advancingTimersByTime.
Fixed test looks like this:


import { mount, flushPromises } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { describe, it, expect, vi } from 'vitest';
import SimpleList from '@/components/rs/RsAnalysis/ImageAnalysis/SimpleList.vue';
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

describe('SimpleList with async setup', () => {
  it('renders the title and items when wrapped in Suspense', async () => {
    vi.useFakeTimers();
    const WrapperComponent = defineComponent({
      components: { SimpleList },
      template: `
        <Suspense>
          <template #default>
            <SimpleList :items="['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']" />
          </template>
          <template #fallback>
            <div>Loading...</div>
          </template>
        </Suspense>
      `,
    });

    const wrapper = mount(WrapperComponent);

    // Wait for async operations
    vi.advanceTimersByTime(1500);
    await flushPromises();

    // Test for the title rendered from async setup
    const title = wrapper.find('h1');
    expect(title.exists()).toBe(true);
    expect(title.text()).toBe('Async Loaded Title');

    // Test for the list items
    const listItems = wrapper.findAll('li');
    expect(listItems).toHaveLength(3);
    expect(listItems[0].text()).toBe('Item 1');
    expect(listItems[1].text()).toBe('Item 2');
    expect(listItems[2].text()).toBe('Item 3');
  });
});



Thanks for the answer in vue-test-utils git: https://github.com/vuejs/test-utils/issues/2528#issuecomment-2429405980
